# Internal HDs that don't contain the OS aren't accessable unless I try to manually browse them

Tags: 12.04, mount, hard-drive, disk, automount

So I have 4 internal hard drives, one that contains the OS (Ubuntu 12.04), all ext4. After starting the computer up, and without having tried to access the drives (File manager, terminal etc) it seems like the drives haven't been mounted. If I go into the "Disks"  utility I see that the disks haven't been mounted.

Programs that try to access the HD's during startup throw an error. For example my music player can't find the library, my note taking software can't find the database etc. But after opening the drive in a file manager everything works.

I've checked SMART on all the disks and everything is a ok.

Any and all ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Disks again and click in a drive/partition (except for the one Ubuntu is on), then the two cogs and Edit mount options.

Set automatic mount options to false and tick the mount on startup to have the drive mount when the computer is started.

Now in the terminal type `sudo mount -a` to test if it will mount successfully, also click the mount (play icon) in disks to test if it will mount.

Ext4s will most probably have a mount error when 'Show in interface' is ticked due to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1011257) and [outstanding fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1012081). Turning it off should fix it, but then you will have to go to the mount location directly to open it, since it won't display in the interface - you can add a bookmark to the mount location to overcome this (temporally until this is fixed).

Comment: Causes a mount error while booting and removes the drives from the file manager. They are marked as mounted, and in use though. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What errors are you getting? The command in the answer should give the same errors without you needing to reboot.

Comment: @Hrafn I have made an edit that might help with the mount error.

Comment: Ah sorry for the radio silence, I've been and still am out of town not near that particular computer. Will try what you suggested in the coming days. Thx for the extended answer.